# open a PDF in windows Form

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to load a pdf into a axAcroPDF using [this](http://www.screencast.com/t/JXRhGvzvB) method that I found here. but there isn't a `this.axAcroPDF.LoadFile()` there. The error message that I get says:

> "AxacroPDFLib.AxacroPDF doesn't contain a defection for 'LoadFile' and
>   no Extension method excepting first method of a type
>   AxacroPDFLib.AxacroPDF could be found (Are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?"

So I double checked and there are Acrobat , AcroPDFLib, AxAcroPDFLib Referances in the WPF and user control.

Next I goggled this again and found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a59LvC6BOuk) on YouTube that uses `this.axAcroPDF.src =path;` however I do not this option either. Please tell me if they have changed the LoadFile(path) to something else, or if there is a reference that I am missing?

Comment: Have you created a user control on your form called axAcroPDF?  If you change the code to:  "if ( axAcroPDF != null ) {}"  without the quotes, does it compile?

Answer (score 0):

```
axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(PDFPath.ToString());
axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false); //disable pdf toolbar.
axAcroPDF1.Enabled = true;
```

Another solution is to set the `src` property of your Axacro control.

Comment: Adam none of those are in there either.

Comment: is there another solution? my question hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Did you add the axAcro reference and did you add it to the top in your `using` statement?

Comment: Yes, I am using Adobe Reader DC, it is the object browser, but they do it doesn't accept the function name.

Comment: Do you get any methods to come up in intellisense when you do `axAcroPDF1.`

Comment: Which ones for example.